# newcommand, section

Tags: macros, sectioning, errors

I just received a new task in LaTex with a predefined structure and predefined commands. There was also the command `\mysection`. I think it shouldn't show the text of the section in the document, but should use it for the headline on each side and for the table of contents:

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}\sectionmark{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\arabic{section}}{#1}}}
```

There was an already completed document, and the command was used like this:

```
\mysection{Die rationalen Zahlen $\Qe_0^+$}
```

So I think it worked, but when I try to compile, it always shows me the error:

> ! Argument of \XKV@d@fine@k@y has an extra }.\par
>   \mysection{Die rationalen Zahlen $\Qe_0^+$}
>
> ! Paragraph ended before \XKV@d@fine@k@y was complete.\par \mysection{Die rationalen Zahlen $\Qe_0^+$}

In fact, a friend of mine try to compile it on his mac and it's working. Is it just a missing package? What should I try do fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Probably a problem due to the blank line. Remove it.

Comment: your code fails for me because `\Qe` isn't defined.  the error you get is typical of expanding a macro which shouldn't be expanded in the context.  my guess is that `\Qe` does a conditional expansion, but that doesn't quite square with somebody offering the code as an example.  as @ChristianHupfer says, we need an mwe.

Comment: VtC as unclear. With the given information it is impossible to give precise answer. Please improve your question by adding a minimal working example as requested before.